# Dynamically modify column DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Please forgive me if I have not capitalized something correctly. I'm used to Java, but I'm trying to adhere to C# convention!

I'm having trouble dynamically setting the data for a column in a DataGrid. I successfully added columns set the column headers dynamically, but I can't seem to set the data. Here's what the result is:
[image: A data grid without rows]

The data is being read, and columnData contains the correct values, as the logger tells me. (I'm not using the Debug class because I'm testing on a machine that doesn't have Visual C#).

My DataGrid class is where the problem lies, I think. Moreover, I think the problem lies in how I'm using the binding (I don't have a good grasp of how to do it, yet)

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace mdr
{
    class MDRResult : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
    {
        private string[] headers;

        private string[][] fields;

        public MDRResult(string[] headers, string[][] fields) : base()
        {

            int columnNumber = 0;
            foreach (string s in headers)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn column = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                column.Header = s;
                string[] columnData = new string[fields.Length];
                int rowNumber = 0;
                foreach (string[] row in fields)
                {
                    columnData[rowNumber] = row[columnNumber];
                    rowNumber++;
                }
                SurfaceWindow1.logger.WriteLine("Adding column " + s + " with data ");
                foreach (string str in columnData)
                    SurfaceWindow1.logger.WriteLine("\t" + str);
                Binding b = new Binding();
                //b.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;
                b.Source = columnData;
                column.Binding = b;
                Columns.Add(column);
                columnNumber++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My XAML is paired with another class. Here is the XAML:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="mdr.SurfaceWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    Title="SurfaceApplication1" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Grid Background="#FFC7C7C7">
        <s:ScatterView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="248,1,0,0" Name="resultsView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFDBDBDB" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        </s:ScatterView>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="270">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="274*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="307*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
                <s:SurfaceTextBox Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="70,0,0,0" Name="fileLocation" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="173" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="http://endeavour.dartmouth.edu/eva/MDR-SampleData.txt" />
                <Label Content="File:" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="FileLabel" Width="50" Foreground="Black" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 70, 0, 0">
                <s:SurfaceTextBox Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="70,0,0,0" Name="cv" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="173" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="10" />
                <Label Content="CV:" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="CVLabel" Width="50" Foreground="Black" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="400" Margin="0, 120, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="270">
            <s:SurfaceSlider ValueChanged="minSlider_ValueChanged" Grid.Row="1" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,6,0,0" Name="minSlider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Orientation="Vertical" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="1" />
            <s:SurfaceSlider ValueChanged="maxSlider_ValueChanged" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,46,0" Name="maxSlider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="False" Orientation="Vertical" Value="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="1" />
            <Label Content="Min: 1" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,133,0,0" Name="minLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" Foreground="Black" />
            <Label Content="Max: 1" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,133,0,0" Name="maxLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Foreground="Black" />
            <Label Content="Level" Grid.Row="1" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Foreground="Black" />
        </Grid>
        <s:SurfaceButton Click="onMDRSubmit" Content="Run" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,0,0,40" Name="runButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="172" FontSize="32" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF9A9A9A" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

And here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Surface;
using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation;
using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls;
using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Input;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace mdr
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SurfaceWindow1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SurfaceWindow1 : SurfaceWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        MDRInterface mdr;
        public static StreamWriter logger;
        public static String directory;
        public SurfaceWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Add handlers for window availability events
            AddWindowAvailabilityHandlers();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the window is about to close. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);

            // Remove handlers for window availability events
            RemoveWindowAvailabilityHandlers();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds handlers for window availability events.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddWindowAvailabilityHandlers()
        {
            // Subscribe to surface window availability events
            ApplicationServices.WindowInteractive += OnWindowInteractive;
            ApplicationServices.WindowNoninteractive += OnWindowNoninteractive;
            ApplicationServices.WindowUnavailable += OnWindowUnavailable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes handlers for window availability events.
        /// </summary>
        private void RemoveWindowAvailabilityHandlers()
        {
            // Unsubscribe from surface window availability events
            ApplicationServices.WindowInteractive -= OnWindowInteractive;
            ApplicationServices.WindowNoninteractive -= OnWindowNoninteractive;
            ApplicationServices.WindowUnavailable -= OnWindowUnavailable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the user can interact with the application's window.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnWindowInteractive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO: enable audio, animations here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the user can see but not interact with the application's window.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnWindowNoninteractive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO: Disable audio here if it is enabled

            //TODO: optionally enable animations here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the application's window is not visible or interactive.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnWindowUnavailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO: disable audio, animations here
        }

        private void AddMDRResult(string result)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string[] rows = result.Split('\n');
            foreach (string s in rows[0].Split('\t'))
            {
                if (s.Length == 0) continue;
                logger.WriteLine("Adding header " + s);
                table.Columns.Add(s);
            }

            bool first = true;
            foreach (string s in rows)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                    continue;
                }
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                int i = 0;
                logger.WriteLine("Row " + table.Rows.Count + ": ");
                foreach (string value in s.Split('\t'))
                {
                    if (value.Length == 0)
                        continue;
                    logger.WriteLine("\t element " + i + ": " + value);
                    row[i] = value;
                    i++;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    logger.Write(row[i] + "\t");

                logger.WriteLine();
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            DataView view = table.AsDataView();

            ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();
            ArrayList headersList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string s in rows[0].Split('\t'))
            {
                if (s.Length == 0) continue;
                headersList.Add(s);
            }

            object[] list = headersList.ToArray();
            string[] headers = new string[list.Length];

            for(int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                headers[i] = list[i].ToString();

            ArrayList fieldList = new ArrayList();
            first = true;
            foreach (string s in rows)
            {
                if (first) {first = false; continue;}
                int i = 0;
                string[] row = new string[headers.Length];
                foreach (string value in s.Split('\t'))
                {
                    if (value.Length == 0)
                        continue;
                    row[i] = value;
                    i++;
                }
                fieldList.Add(row);
            }

            list = fieldList.ToArray();
            string[][] fields = new string[list.Length][];

            for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                fields[i] = (string[])(list[i]);

            item.Content = new MDRResult(headers, fields);

            item.Width = 500;
            item.Height = 500;

            resultsView.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void onMDRSubmit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (logger == null)
            {
                directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                if (directory[directory.Length - 1] == '\\')
                    directory = directory.Substring(0, directory.Length - 1);
                String logFile = directory + "\\log\\surface.txt";
                Debug.WriteLine("Creating log file: " + logFile);
                if (File.Exists(logFile))
                    File.Delete(logFile);
                Directory.CreateDirectory("\\log\\");
                FileStream stream = File.Create(logFile);
                logger = new StreamWriter(stream);
                logger.AutoFlush = true;
            }
            if (mdr == null)
            {
                logger.WriteLine("Initializing MDR wrapper...");
                mdr = new MDRInterface();
                logger.WriteLine("Initialized MDR wrapper!");
            }
            logger.WriteLine("Starting MDR...");
            string text = cv.Text;
            string result = mdr.RunMDR(int.Parse(text), (int)minSlider.Value, (int)maxSlider.Value, (long)0, fileLocation.Text);
            logger.WriteLine("Finished MDR! Adding to results list.");
            AddMDRResult(result);
        }

        private void minSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.NewValue > maxSlider.Value)
                    minSlider.Value = e.OldValue;
                minLabel.Content = "Min: " + minSlider.Value;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                //ignore
            }
        }

        private void maxSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.NewValue < minSlider.Value)
                    maxSlider.Value = e.OldValue;
                maxLabel.Content = "Max: " + maxSlider.Value;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the XAML as well.

Comment: @Rhyous I did that, although I don't think it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
class MDRResult : DataGrid
{
    public MDRResult(string[] headers, string[][] fields)
        : base()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; ++i)
            this.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = headers[i],
                Binding = new Binding("[" + i + "]")
            });
        this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.ItemsSource = fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: ItemsSource for your DataGrid is of type string[][]. That means that DataContext for every row is of type string[]. Value for each column is read from this string[] instance, using the indexer property [0], [1], [2],... specified in the binding.

Comment: So if I set ItemsSource to something other than a 2d array, what would happen?

Comment: You would have to change Binding path to point to the name of the properties of items in ItemsSource or allow DataGrid to create columns automatically by removing entire code that generates columns and this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
statement.